# args to be in the same query of the function without mention it in every function

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

I have multiple resolvers where all of them have functions call the same argument for example
country resolver

```
get country(@Args() x:xModel,..)
get countries(@Args() x:xModel,..)
book resolver
get books(@Args() x:xModel,..)
get authorBook(@Args() x:xModel,..)
```

I need this x args to be in the same query of the function without mention it in every function
I tried inheritance it gives me a separated query for the function query args
any ideas?